# Closure in subspace topology being closed in parent topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an <strike>arbitrary</strike> path-connected set inheriting the subspace topology from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does there always exist an open subset of $X$ (in the subspace topology) whose closure in the subspace topology is also closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Not any open subset will do, as we can see from the following example. Consider $X = (0,3) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $X$ is its own closure in $X$, but is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. However, we could choose the open subset $(1,2) \subset X$ whose closure is $[1,2]$ both in $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

If this is not the case, are there some mild conditions on $X$ that would make this true (e.g. connectedness)? If $X$ is itself closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the above is trivial.

Comment: $\mathbb Q^n$ seems like a counterexample off the top of my head

Comment: @athalhaids I appreciate the example -- I guess I'm really only interested in relatively "normal" subsets (purposefully ambiguous). I'll edit my question to assume path connectedness.

Comment: Then what about the complement of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$? This space is path-connected iff $n \ge 2$.

Comment: @Zerox foiled again... Maybe my actual question here should be "what is the weakest condition that makes the above true?" Intuitively, I'm looking for something a little weaker than being closed--I don't care if sequences going to the "edges" of the set don't have a limit point in the set, but I want the surface to be "filled in" on its interior.

The best thing I can think of right now is a manifold, but possibly there's something simpler. I'm guessing that the above is probably true for a manifold... will try to prove it.

Comment: A candidate for the "filled in" condition on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is probably "locally compact" in the subspace topology. Compactness is precisely the abstraction of "no holes to fill in".